# Is it possible to launch dask clusters on hpc (slurm) remotely from local computer?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am new to Dask, I understand that to start the dask clusters, I would normally have to ssh to my hpc cluster and then start SLURMCluster() to start some clusters, then after it's started I need to Client('node_ip') on my local computer. I was wondering if it's possible to launch the dask clusters on my local computer without having to login to the HPC first.

Comment: Putting dask aside, is it possible to start an SGE job without logging into the cluster ?